# Mark methods in class as "should not be invoked because the system already does this automatically"?

Tags: java, public

I'm using Java 1.7. I have a class `"ItemFactory"` inside a .jar that allows other developers to create Item objects (item has a private constructor). The factory requires some user input to create certain items. Recently I added some items which also require input, but all the necessary data is already present in the system. I thought it would be esier for developers to let my `"ItemHandler"` class automatically create these items. So instead having them type this:

```
ItemFactory factory = new ItemFactory();
Item item = factory.createItem(parameter1, parameter2);
ItemHandler handler = new ItemHandler();
handler.doSomethingCool(item);
```

They could simply do this:

```
handler.doSomethingCool()
```

and the `doSomethingCool()` method will make the item automatically from the factory because all necessary input is already present in the system.

My problem is now that the facotry class suddenly has public methods that should not be visible. For example, the public method createItemForSomethingCoolPurposes(), is automatically invoked by the system itself and developers needed worry about it. It's potentially confusing for them to see this method because it's not clear what its purpose is. Adding comments/documentation to express "this method should not be called" seems stupid. Am I wrong on this? Is this a common problem, and are there conventions about it?

Answer (score 2):

Simply refactor those methods  using the old code which is no longer `public`. If you can't do so because you don't have control over the code using your api mark those methods `@Deprecated` and add a note that in the next version it will be removed. So you simply need to communicate your intention to remove the `public` methods and after everyone refactored their code you can remove the code.

This is what the developers of the java sdk are doing as well. They mark obsolete code `@Deprecated` add a link and an example to the new code and remove the obsolete code in the next release.

Comment: Refactor what exactly? The item has to be created in the itemFactory class because item has a private constructor, but the methods needing the items are in another package. so I don't see how I can refactor the getItem method to something else.

Comment: I assume that your users are alraedy using your `public` methods. So in order to change them to `private` for example you need to refactor all code using those methods.

Comment: I can't make them private, they need to be public so my own classes can still get to them. it's external clsses (not part of my jar) that needn't be calling them. Something like protected, but which spans over multiple packages ;(

Answer (score 0):

You could probably refactor the method to be package-private.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

For more info on the topic, read Effective Java (3rd ed):

ITEM 15: MINIMIZE THE ACCESSIBILITY OF CLASSES AND MEMBERS

---

Alternatively using Google's error-prone library you could annotate it with @DoNotCall and also add a @Deprecated annotation so IDE users get immediate feedback that they should not call that method.